# Lenovo n200 3000 very low sound on headphone jack

Tags: audio, lenovo-laptop

When I plugin my headphones I got very low sound on one side(left), right side has no sound at all. Speakers built in laptop works fine. Output for headphones stop working well few days ago. When I boot Ubuntu, I got same problem. So drivers and settings are not solution. It seems its a hardware problem. Does anyone has any idea what to do now or have had same problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like the problem is the headphones themselves - have you tried them on something besides this laptop?  Some of the wiring is probably just worn out from flex or what have you.

Comment: it seems that problem is inside laptop, on sound card. I dont know if it would help to open it..

Comment: Opening it isn't going to do you any good unless the jack itself is physically loose - if the connector is seating properly then that's that.  It's a really unusual problem and probably the issue is in the internal wiring and not the actual jack itself.  I would probably test a pair of external speakers as well, just to be sure.  If it is a problem with the jack, the easiest thing to do is probably just buy a little external USB sound card and use that instead.

Comment: External USB sound card is solution.. Simple, thank you for advice.

Comment: @spiatrax - No problem, glad you're up and running with a minimum of fuss.

Answer (score 0):

Smells like the connector on either the headset or laptop could be shot. This kind of thing will happen if the connector isn't connecting properly on all the rings of the jack. Have you tried a different headset?

If that doesn't work then see if there's any difference if you give the connector a little jiggle while it's plugged in to figure out whether it's the laptop's connector that is having the problem.

Comment: i tried different headphones and same problem. Jiggling connector doesnt make any difference, not even noise while jiggling.

Answer (score -2):

Had the same prob. When you want to view something using headphones make sure phones plugged in BEFORE you start to view., ie plug in headphones, refresh page and sound should work through phones then.